# What are the requirements for attribution in the MIT License?

Tags: licensing, mit-license

[choosealicense.com](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/) claims that the [MIT license](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/) is “A permissive license that is short and to the point. It lets people do anything with your code **with proper attribution** and without warranty” (emphasis mine). Reading the license, though, I don’t see anything claiming that attribution to the original author has to be anywhere, so where are they taking that from?

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/5828/6368

Comment: MIT defines the word Software's meaning for us in [`this software and associated documentation files (the "Software")`] paragraph, and obviously MIT paragraph starts with "this software" (not "the Software") and puts the quotes around "`Software`" alone (meaning, wherever "Software" is mentioned from that point on, their original content was meant) and later MIT asks "substantial portions of the Software" to attribute, but remember that Software is their original work (i.e. if you got binary from them, then you must attribute where ever you use that binary, else just ensure you compile/Uglify)

Comment: While some jurisdictions may define the default meaning of "The Software"; What is the definition of "this" in jurisdiction? MIT License calls the entire original content "this software" and defines "Software" to mean same. And although very short, MIT does undeniably specify what "Software" means, and excludes default jurisdiction meanings (which was the right choice! because in many countries jurisdiction meanings differ)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The fourth paragraph says that the copyright notice in the second paragraph must be reproduced. Users of the licence substitute the [fullname] with their actual name. That is what constitutes "proper attribution" in the mind of the MIT: every user of the software can find out who wrote it if they want to.

Comment: The [other answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/311309/319915) is right that (at least in MIT license) **"Software" is referring to their original *software*, and not to our derivative binary**; but "substantial portions" part is dangerous! I mean, for languages like `JavaScript` ensure to Uglify (or attribute at top of your file)

Comment: For more details about how and why, see [my post on same matter](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/11976/11200).

Comment: You don't always have to attribute at the top of the file unless the original author did. If the attribution is in a separate license file, then that probably should suffice, as long as it is clear to what the license refers to.

Answer (score 6):

Note: before you mercilessly downvote - please understand the four-corners legal principle, international interpretation, and the Usage of Trade principle, and of course - be objective.

I've found answers convincing me both ways.
The short answer is, you probably should, just because it's nice.

In MIT's case I feel people take it for granted that attribution is required for shipping compiled versions, and that the attribution must be visible to the end users. Of course, the good samaritans in us think this would be the default nice thing to do.

Looking at the license I see no evidence for that requirement.

**the Software** has a specific meaning in the MIT license.

> ...this software and associated documentation files (the "Software")

**the Software** is not explicitly your works, derivations, adaptations or compiled versions. If it were, then it could be considered as a viral licence like GPL.

...

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Remember, **the Software** is their software, not yours.

If you are submitting open source code to github and included the Software, then absolutely, it means keep the LICENSE.TXT and copyright headers.

But for a product....
The MIT licence does not indicate that there must be **public** attribution in your end product, but that the notice shall be included in **their** software. If it was compiled in it's a grey area.

This first clause may also stem from old-law.

> "Copyright laws used to require that copyrighted works carry an
>   explicit notice in published forms to receive copyright protection"
>   [Understanding Open Source and Free Software Licensing](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/osfreesoft/book/ch02.pdf)

However, there are many who believe the opposite.
It doesn't hurt you to attribute. 
It's nice, just don't accidentally licence your own product as MIT in the process unless you want to.

Comment: I think this answer is very confusing. People don't take attribution of the MIT license for granted. It says _right in the license_ "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software." It's hard to make it any more clear than that. You can't take something for granted that is explicitly stated.

Comment: The main point was the use of 'the Software', which doesn't  necessarily mean 'your software or derivative works'.

Comment: What constitutes a "substantial portion?"  With GitHub being used more frequently like a programmer's personal scratch pad, snippets of code are getting shorter and shorter; more and more trivial.

Comment: @BryanOakley Answer is right that (at least in MIT license) **"Software" is referring to their original *software*, and not to our derivative binary**; but "substantial portions" part is dangerous! I mean, for languages like `JavaScript` ensure to Uglify (or attribute at top of your file)

Answer (score -1):

MIT defines the word Software's meaning for us in the statement:

> **`this software and associated documentation files (the "Software")`**

- and obviously MIT paragraph starts with "this software" (not "the Software") and puts the quotes around "`Software`" alone, **meaning, wherever "Software" is mentioned from that point on, their original content was meant,**
- then later MIT asks "`substantial portions of the Software`" to attribute,
- but remember that Software is their original work:

  - **If you got anything-pre-compiled or binary from them, then you must attribute wherever you use that binary,**
  - **Else just ensure you compile/Uglify.**

  > Of course, if original-content includes both binary-files (like images) and source-files, simply using only their source-files is possible (instead of attribution).

  - I mean, because any sane person knows that the compiler-generated-output (aka binary) of source is normally **not** a "`substantial portion`" of the original source.

### What original content:

While some jurisdictions may define the [default meaning of "The Software"](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4918/11200), which sometimes excludes images, like in U.S. law where *software* means:

> "Computer programs that comprise a series of instructions, rules, routines, or statements, regardless of the media in which recorded, that allow or cause a computer to perform a specific operation or series of operations"

What is the definition of "this" in jurisdiction?

- MIT License calls the entire original content "this software" and defines "Software" to mean same.
- And although very short, MIT does undeniably specify what "Software" means, and excludes default jurisdiction meanings
- MIT made the right choice! because in many countries jurisdiction meanings differ.

### Moral right

But about **moral right** (not MIT), I agree with [another answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/8163/11200), and it's description:

Whether or not the license spells attribution-requirements out, the authors of the software still have a **moral right** to be recognized as the authors. Moral rights are a part of copyright that is independent from the economic rights. I do not interpret licenses without strong attribution requirements as a waiver of these moral rights, in fact moral rights are sometimes unwaivable. However, moral rights differ substantially between jurisdictions. In common law jurisdictions and especially the US, moral rights are extremely weak and do not seem to apply to software.

However, you are only bound by the laws from which you first publish your software. Applicability of that in the age of the internet is not entirely clear, but if you publish a software from a country, you should at least comply with the copyright laws of that country. You may therefore have to respect the moral rights anyway, and provide attribution for all works included in the software you publish. What licenses do and don't require is secondary to those concerns.

In Sweden, Art 3 of the Copyright Act covers the right to attribution, and when it may be waived.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Please have an open mind, and try to ignore the harsh fact that if this is true, then all of your own MIT Licensed work does NOT force any attribution to be displayed in Apps (at least not until they replace all images and binary)

Comment: If you can prove me wrong then plz do that in comments! But if you want more quality (and think you can do better), there should be an edit button somewhere ;-)

Comment: "wherever "Software" is mentioned [in the MIT license] from that point on, their original content was meant" - Are you saying that modified versions of the MIT-licensed software are themselves not longer considered "the Software" in MIT terms? I suppose, that's one interpretation, but that interpretation doesn't really make sense once one reads a bit further in the MIT permissions, since the license explicitly allows you "the rights to use, copy, *modify*, *merge*, publish, distribute, *sublicense*, *and/or* sell copies of the Software."

Comment: Also remember that the default stance in copyright law is normally that you're not allowed to distribute derivatives or modifications without permission. So, if the above interpretation (that "the Software" only referred to the original software), then the result would be that there's nothing in the MIT license that gives you permission to distribute your modified "software" since, at that point, the modified Software is no longer truly "this software" by your interpretation. In any case, I believe this  interpretation is confusing and not what was intended by the license.

Comment: **Wrong, MIT explicitly gives permission for both modify and distribute** (in this order); I say "binary" is not what was meant with "this", hence we don't need to attribute.

Comment: @Brandin Hence your calim that "`then modify and distribute would not be allowed`" dissolves to nothing, because "binary" was never even mentioned in MIT, but both "modify" and "distribute" are explicitly allowed.

Comment: MIT license does not distinguish between source and binary forms. From a plain language reading, 'software' could refer to either of those, in my opinion. So, "this software" refers to in whatever form you got it in.

Comment: @Brandin exactly; my answer already mentions that **if you got it in "binary" form, either remove that binary and keep source(s) only, or you are forced to attribute.**